# How can I use Vulkan in Android with my own Activity?

Tags: java, android, vulkan

I have downloaded googlesamples: [vulkan-basic-samples](https://github.com/googlesamples/vulkan-basic-samples), compiled and executed this samples. Howevew ,I found all of this samples specified a `NativeActivity` in their `AndroidManifest.xml`, such as:

```
    <!-- Our activity is the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
         This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
    <activity android:name="android.app.NativeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
        <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of or .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="vulkan_samples" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

But I want to use my own Activity(in Java), please tell me How. 
Thanks!

Comment: I guess binding Java to Vulkan is under heavy development. There is a LWJGL port and my own Bor_Vulkan at github. Along side the 1:1 binding for Java and Vulkan, android requires a SurfaceView subclassing, just like GLSurfaceView does for GLES. This VulkanSurfaceView must deal with Vulkan's WSI to pass ANativeWindow pointer to surface to draw. Easy.

Comment: It means that I need  a tool like `VulkanSurfaceView` ,maybe a tool like `EGL`  with my own Activity( such as `MyActivity.java`) ?  @Alex Byrth

Comment: Hi ! I just open an issue at Bor_Vulkan, where I put relevant points about implementing VulkanSurfaceView.java, at   [GitHub](https://github.com/AlessandroBorges/Bor_Vulkan/issues/1)

Comment: Hi , I added  comment on your GitHub.